# Реализовать класс "наследник"

Tags: c++, ооп

Spisok.h

```
  #pragma once
  class Spisok
  {
  int size1;
  int size2;
  int **mas;

 public:
 Spisok(int,int);
 ~Spisok();
 int get(int, int); // выводим значений отдельных элементов
 void get(); // выводим матрицу
 void sort1(int); //сортировка по номеру строки
 void sort2(int); //сортировка по номеру столбца
 };
```

Spisok.cpp

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "Spisok.h"
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include<iostream>
 #include<conio.h>

 Spisok::Spisok(int n, int m)
{
size1 = n;
size2 = m;
mas = new int*[size1];
for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    mas[i] = new int[size2];
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
        mas[i][j] = rand() % 100;
 } //инициализация поля и заполнение его рандомными числами
 Spisok::~Spisok()
{
 }
 int Spisok::get(int n, int m)
{
return mas[n - 1][m - 1];
}//вывод определённой ячейки
void Spisok::get()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
{
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
        std::cout << mas[i][j] << "\t";
}
}//вывод матрицы
 void Spisok::sort1(int n)
{
for (int i = 0; i < size2 - 1; i++)
{
    if (mas[n][i] > mas[n][i + 1])
    {
        int z;
        z = mas[n][i];
        mas[n][i] = mas[n][i + 1];
        mas[n][i + 1] = z;
        i = -1;
    }
 }
  }//сортировка по номеру строки
 void Spisok::sort2(int n)
 {
for (int i = 0; i < size1 - 1; i++)
{
    if (mas[i][n] > mas[i + 1][n])
    {
        int z;
        z = mas[i][n];
        mas[i][n] = mas[i + 1][n];
        mas[i + 1][n] = z;
        i = -1;
    }
}
}//сортировка по номеру столбца
```

Главный файл

```
  #include "Spisok.h" 
  #include <iostream> 
  #include <stdio.h> 
  #include <locale.h> 
  #include <windows.h> 
  using namespace std;

  int main()
 {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int i = 1, n = 1, m = 1;
Spisok *T = nullptr;
while (i != 0)
{
    cout << endl << "Напишите, что вы хотите сделать";
    cout << endl << "1)Cоздать матрицу";
    cout << endl << "2)Получить число по положению";
    cout << endl << "3)Получить матрицу";
    cout << endl << "4)Отсортировать по строке";
    cout << endl << "5)Отсортировать по столбцу";
    cout << endl << "6)Завершить программу" << endl;
    int b;
    cin >> b;
    switch (b)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        cout << endl << "Введите размеры списка\n";
        int n, m;
        cin >> n >> m;
        T = new Spisok(n, m);
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        if (T == nullptr)
            std::cout << "Не заданы размеры матрицы!!!\n";
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "Введите положение\n";
            int n, m;
            cin >> n >> m;
            cout << "\nЧисло в этом положении =" << T->get(n, m);
        }
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        if (T == nullptr)
            std::cout << "Не заданы размеры матрицы!!!\n";
        else
            T->get();
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        if (T == nullptr)
            std::cout << "Не заданы размеры матрицы!!!\n";
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "Введите номер строки \n";
            int z;
            cin >> z;
            T->sort1(z - 1);
        }
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        if (T == nullptr)
            std::cout << "Не заданы размеры матрицы!!!\n";
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "Введите номер столбца\n";
            int z;
            cin >> z;
            T->sort2(z - 1);
        }
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    {
        i = 0; break;
    }
    default:
    {
        cout << "Такой ф-ции нет, попробуйте снова";
        break;
    }
    }
}
return 0;
 }
```

Помогите реализовать класс наследник содержащий дополнительные методы вычисления скалярного произведения двух заданных строк и/или двух заданных столбцов.
Заранее огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: а почему то матрица, то список? В чем именно помочь? Что не получилось?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
class CustomSpisok : public Spisok{  
public:
    CustomSpisok(int x, int y):
        Spisok(x, y)
    {}
    int mulColumns(int x, int y) const{
        //Реализация умножения столбцов
    }
    int mulRows(int x, int y) const{
        //Реализация произведения строк
    }
};
```

Но у вас в коде есть другие проблемы. Во-первых, вы выделяете память в конструкторе через `new`, но не освобождаете её в деструкторе. Получается утечка памяти. 
Деструктор должен выглядеть так:

```
Spisok::~Spisok(){
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++){
        delete[] mas[i];
    }
    delete mas;
 }
```

Во-вторых, деструктор базового класса всегда должен быть объявлен виртуальным.

```
virtual ~Spisok();
```

Если хотите узнать подробнее почему, можете почитать правило 7 в книге Скотта Майерса Effective C++, ну или оформить это как другой вопрос.